# How to insert rows into a table based on another table's rows using Triggers?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, bulkinsert

I have three tables:

Employee

```
Id
FirstName
LastName
EmployeeTasksId
```

EmployeeTasks

```
Id
EmployeeId
EmployeeTaskDefinitionId
```

EmployeeTaskDefinitions

```
Id
Description
etc.
```

What I am trying to do is once an `Employee` is inserted into the `Employees` table, I need to insert rows into the `EmployeeTasks` table based on the inserted `Employee's` Id and every `EmployeeTaskDefinition's Id.`

For example:

- `Employee` with `Id` 1 is inserted into Employee table
- `EmployeeTaskDefinitions` table has 6 rows with `Ids` 1-6
- `EmployeeTasks` table needs to have 6 rows after this insert:

  ```
  Id = 1, EmployeeId = 1, EmployeeTaskDefinitonId = 1    
  Id = 2, EmployeeId = 1, EmployeeTaskDefinitonId = 2     
  Id = 3, EmployeeId = 1, EmployeeTaskDefinitonId = 3      
  Id = 4, EmployeeId = 1, EmployeeTaskDefinitonId = 4      
  Id = 5, EmployeeId = 1, EmployeeTaskDefinitonId = 5      
  Id = 6, EmployeeId = 1, EmployeeTaskDefinitonId = 6
  ```

Now I have read numerous posts about cursors, with most people saying that they're a bad practice to use for this task. But how would you do something like this? Note: I don't want to use anything else other than triggers.

EDIT: This is the query I came up with.

```
CREATE TRIGGER CreateEmployee 
    ON [dbo].[EmployeeSet]
    AFTER INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @LoopCounter int, @MaxSettingDefinitionId int, @Id int
    SELECT @LoopCounter = MIN(Id), @MaxSettingDefinitionId = MAX(Id)
    FROM SettingsDefinitionSet

    WHILE(@LoopCounter IS NOT NULL AND @LoopCounter <= @MaxSettingDefinitionId)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Id = Id FROM SettingDefinitionSet
        WHERE Id = @LoopCounter
        INSERT INTO SettingSet(CompanyId, EmployeeId, SettingDefinitionId, SettingType, State, Value)
        VALUES((SELECT CompanyId FROM inserted), (SELECT Id FROM inserted), 
                @Id, 
                (SELECT SettingType FROM SettingSet WHERE EmployeeId IS NULL AND CompanyId = (SELECT CompanyId FROM inserted) AND SettingDefinitionId = @Id), 
                (SELECT State FROM SettingSet WHERE EmployeeId IS NULL AND CompanyId = (SELECT CompanyId FROM inserted) AND SettingDefinitionId = @Id), 
                (SELECT Value FROM SettingSet WHERE EmployeeId IS NULL AND CompanyId = (SELECT CompanyId FROM inserted) AND SettingDefinitionId = @Id))
        SELECT @LoopCounter = MIN(Id) FROM SettingDefinitionSet
        WHERE Id > @LoopCounter
    END
GO
```

Comment: Cursors inside a trigger are the **ultimate** NO NO in SQL Server. A trigger executes in the context of the statement that caused it to fire, and that statement doesn't complete until the trigger is done. Therefore, a trigger **must remain** small, nimble, fast - do **NOT** do any heavy lifting inside a trigger, massive calculations, external calls (web services), do not send e-mails from within triggers etc. - and using a **cursor** in that context is the ultimate performance sin you can commit... don't do it! EVER!!

Comment: no worries mate. one question though, does the same apply if the size of the sql query is too large? I have come up with a query that works, but I am not sure if it's too large. please see my answer for the query. note that I will still optimize the query a little.

Comment: First of all `Employee` table schema is wrong. `EmployeeTaskId` should not be there. Consider what happens when an employee has several tasks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just thought up those three tables on the fly as I was typing my question. In reality, my DB schema is way more complex so I didn't want to show the actual thing here as it would just take away the focus from my actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeTasks(EmployeeId, EmployeeTaskDefinitionId)
SELECT inserted.id as EmployeeId, t.id as EmployeeTaskDefinitionId
    FROM inserted JOIN EmployeeTaskDefinitions
```

Comment: where does this go? into the trigger body between the AS and GO keywords?

Comment: Yes, in the trigger body

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in comments, `Employee` table is bad normalized and shouldn't have `EmployeeTasksId`. If you want to add automatically some tasks to a new employee do it like this:

```
alter table EmployeeTaskDefinitions
add DefaultTask bit not null default 0
--update EmployeeTaskDefinitions set DefaultTask = 1 where...
--now create a trigger
create trigger trEmployee_i
on dbo.Employee after insert
as
begin
set nocount on
insert EmployeeTasks(EmployeeId,EmployeeTaskDefinitionId)
select i.id,td.id
from inserted i cross join EmployeeTaskDefinitions td
where td.DefaultTask = 1
end
```

P.S.: I hope `EmployeeTasks.Id` is identity column.

Comment: did you read my reply to your comment? those three tables I described above aren't really in my schema, I just thought them up because my real schema is way more complex. I already came up with a query that works, but I am not sure if it's too complex or not (see my edited question for the query)

Comment: I just show how to resolve the problem in your posted fragment.